# does web2py's DAL automatically create forward references when a child table references the parent?

Tags: data-access-layer, web2py

The following information is from page 270 of the web2py book:

```
person = db.person(id)

for dog in person.dog.select(orderby=db.dog.name):
    print person.name, 'owns', dog.name
```

In this last expressions `person.dog` is a shortcut for

```
db(db.dog.owner==person.id)
```

Now:

The book does not reference a section where the `person` table is defined and I dont believe any prior definition of that table actually had a `dog` column. And it wouldnt make sense if the person table did have a `dog` column, because presumably a person can have many dogs.

So are they saying that somehow the reference from the `dog` table to person automatically created a forward reference from the person to the `dog`, without any explicit column in `person`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing was automatically created in the "person" database table itself. Rather, the DAL Row object representing the record of a given person includes a DAL Set object that represents the set of records in the "dog" table that reference the person. In the code, `person` is a Row object (i.e., `db.person(id)`) -- it has a "dog" attribute, which is just the following DAL Set object:

```
db(db.dog.owner == person.id)
```

which is the set of dogs that reference this person.id. If you do:

```
>>> print db.person(1)
```

you'll see something like:

```
<Row {'name': 'John', 'update_record': <function <lambda> at 0x2b08758>,
'dog': <gluon.dal.Set object at 0x2b00d10>, 'id': 1,
'delete_record': <function <lambda> at 0x2b08b90>}>
```

So, in addition to containing the "name" and "id" values for the record, the Row object includes `update_record()` and `delete_record()` functions as well as a Set object representing the "dog" table records that reference this person. If you print the query associated with that Set object, you get the following:

```
>>> print db.person(1).dog.query
(dog.owner = 1)
```

So, the forward reference is created in the Row object itself. Note, the `db.person(1).dog` attribute is only a Set object defining a query -- it does not contain the actual "dog" table records or even references to their id's. No query is done against the database until you call the `select()` method via `db.person(1).dog.select()`, which will return the actual records from the "dogs" table.